# bootstrap v 4.5.2 tab content not working properly

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the below code

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="notes-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#notes" role="tab" aria-controls="notes" aria-selected="true">Notes</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="statistics-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#statistics" role="tab" aria-controls="statistics" aria-selected="false">Statistics</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="exercises-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#exercises" role="tab" aria-controls="exercises" aria-selected="false">Exercises</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="vocabulary-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#vocabulary" role="tab" aria-controls="vocabulary" aria-selected="false">Vocabulary</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active " id="exercises" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="exercises-tab"><?php include('exercises.php'); ?></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade " id="statistics" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="statistics-tab"><?php include('statistics.php'); ?></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade " id="notes" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="notes-tab"><?php include('notes.php'); ?></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade " id="vocabulary" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="vocabulary-tab"><?php include('editor/show_student_vocabulary.php'); ?></div>
            </div>
```

I activate the connection on exercises.php and I see the content from exercises.php and show_student_vocabulary.php on all tabs.
Until activate the connection to the database I had not this issue.

Any ideas?